# Are there any tutorials for MVVM using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, mvvm

I am interested in learning MVVM. Sadly I cannot find examples and/or tutorials on the internet that use Delphi with database applications.

Can you post links or point me in the direction that I should go?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, where did you look? Because my websearch for "mvvm delphi" seemed promising.

Comment: There will be a session on 21 november. Location Edegem, Belguim. see http://www.be-delphi.com/cms/program. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this CodeRage session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1HP8ZBJxk).

> This session will look at Model-View-ViewModel, one technique that leverages LiveBindings to not only minimize the effort required to slide different UIs in front of your code, but also increases the maintainability and testability of your app as a bonus.